# Login System in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

How to implement a login authentication system using Symfony2. Please let me know if there are any tutorials for this. I implemented login system but i am facing "Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem" error.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend `FOSUserBundle` which will fit most basic needs for authentication system and can be easily adapted.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle

Comment: @SuryaTejaMahidhara You already decided to use a framework instead of "doing it manually" so why wouldn't you use a popular bundle (2.5M installs)?

Answer (score 0):

The security chapter of "the book" covers this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Check out the rest of "the book" here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html